# C# - How to mock this.GetType().Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

In the code I'm working on, I'm forced to test one method where there is a call like this:

```
this.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => ...);
```

I would like to mock this call so that when the call is made an assembly of my choice is retrieved from `this.GetType().Assembly`.
In the assembly there will be fake types that I will use for my assertions

The approach I'm trying (still without success) is using shims, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx).

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Finally, note that I know this is not the right approach to do unit testing. Usually the classes I test are made using dependency I can easily mock. This is an exception as this is an implementation of [Cunsomer-Driven Contracts](https://martinfowler.com/articles/consumerDrivenContracts.html) that is solution-wide and I'm not allowed to change it.

Comment: Are you in a position to refactor that code?

Comment: @Nkosi no :( if I was, I would already have done it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cannot change the code under test, you could use a framework like [TypeMock](https://www.typemock.com/) or [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx). Those frameworks use profiler hooks and can, therefore, redirect every function call made, even calls to third-party libraries.

This would allow you to redirect the call to the getter of `this.GetType().Assembly` and return a preset list of assemblies.